# Scanning all database tables while this is running WSO2 Data Service Project?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio

I opened a dataservice project in Integration Studio. I have provided Oracle database connection using OData. I added a select query that fetches records from one table. Then it takes a long time to run this dataservice project and get it up and running. I think it scans all the tables in the database. As a result it works but takes minutes. Why could this be and how can I solve it?

Comment: Well for comparison, WSO2 Enterprise Integrator takes quite a while to start up. Even if it scans all the tables, it shouldn't be so slow.